# How to set autoLoadEntities: true in connecting Nest js with typeorm

Tags: sql-server, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am setting up config file to connect mssql with Nest js and Typeorm

```
import { SqlServerConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm/driver/sqlserver/SqlServerConnectionOptions';
import { Employee } from './src/employees/employee.entity';

const config: SqlServerConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'mssql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 1433,
  username: 'sa',
  password: 'sa',
  database: 'db1',
  synchronize: false,
};

export default config;
```

I want to add `autoLoadEntities: true` in the config but SqlServerConnectionOptions doesn't accept it. Not sure how to add it correctly?

Comment: Do you want to add `trustServerCertificate` or `autoLoadEntities`? Your question is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `config` does not need to have `autoLoadEntities` property. It is a property used by NestJS and not by typeORM.

`TypeOrmModule.forRoot` accepts an object of type `TypeOrmModuleOptions`:

```js
export declare type TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    retryAttempts?: number;
    retryDelay?: number;
    toRetry?: (err: any) => boolean;
    autoLoadEntities?: boolean;
    keepConnectionAlive?: boolean;
    verboseRetryLog?: boolean;
} & Partial<ConnectionOptions>;
```

Your `config: SqlServerConnectionOptions` is a partial of `ConnectionOptions` which is a partial of `TypeOrmModuleOptions`.

So when you declare your typeORM module, you can use something like the below:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  ...config,
  autoLoadEntities: true,
});
```